# blazor server: Call Web API with Impersonalisation (Windows Authentification)

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-server-side

I call a Web-Api from my server blazor app. Some of the API-Calls needed the calling (windows)user. In my development-enviroment (visual studio with iis express) all is fine. On the web-server the calling users is the application-pool-user - and thats the problem.

My question: Is there a way to call the web-api with the credentials of the current windows user?

I tryed to set the credentials of the HttpClient in startup.cs like this:

```
  services.AddHttpClient<ProposalAssistantWebService>(client => { client.BaseAddress = webServiceBaseUri; }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
        {
            return new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                UseDefaultCredentials = true
            };
        }); ;
```

But it doesnt work...

Also this version did not work:

```
 return new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                Credentials=new NetworkCredential("","","")
            };
```

Some ideas?

Sincerly
Peter

Comment: did you enable your credential management in IIS on the server? have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/management/authentication/credentials/ perhaps that aplies to your setup

Comment: What do you mean about "doesn't work", do you meet any error?  When configure certificate authentication in ASP.NET Core,  we should also complete the following steps in IIS Manager: 1. Select your site from the Connections tab. 2. Double-click the SSL Settings option in the Features View window. 3. Check the Require SSL checkbox, and select the Require radio button in the Client certificates section. Check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configure-your-server-to-require-certificates).

Comment: @Zhi Lv: We do not use certificates. By "doesn't" I mean that the user is not passed on to the Web API. The user of the application pool always arrives there...